# Why does = javascript_include_tag :defaults not work in a haml layout in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Man, WTH is going on with this stuff. You know what that line actually does in Rails 3.1?

```
<script src="/assets/defaults.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

As they say on ESPN, "Come on, man."

I know that assets are no longer treated as second-class citizens. But it seems as if they are unable to even receive a green card in this release candidate. In the new app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Sooooo. Am I supposed to download jquery? What do I do? Because there's nothing in that javascripts directory except application.js.

Aggravating. And yet it's free, so how am I complaining? Anyway, these issues seem pretty basic, but I would appreciate any help you can offer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Rails 3.1 there is no longer a "defaults" as such, but rather what is specified in your `application.js` file are the "defaults". You would include this file using this line:

```
 javascript_include_tag "application"
```

The `jquery` and `jquery_ujs` files come with the `jquery-rails` gem which is in the default Rails 3.1 `Gemfile`.

The `//= require` line in that file tells Sprockets that you want to require a file which in this case would be `jquery.js` from within `jquery-rails`, where the `//= require_tree .` will require all other JavaScript files in the same directory as `application.js` and concatenate them all into one file.

You can read more about [the asset pipeline here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Comment: Thanks RB. This was driving me crazy. I guess nifty-scaffold hasn't caught up. I can't believe the JS files are embedded in the gem. That seems a little bit too "magical" to me. I can't figure out how Sprockets knows to look in that gem, and I don't like it.

Comment: Since the link provided is broken, here's a link to rails documentation about assets pipeline: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html